# Can one create Apache hooks with PHP?

Tags: php, apache, hook

I have googled the topic for a while but haven't found what I'm looking for...

Is there a mod for `PHP` that allows it to act much like `mod_wsgi` or `mod_python` so that one can create Apache hooks using PHP?

For example an equivalent to [WSGIAccesScript](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/AccessControlMechanisms#Host_Access_Controls)?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only if you use a FASTCGI module such as mod_fastcgi or mod_fcgid which implements access checker hook defined as part of FASTCGI. Obviously, you need be running PHP via FASTCGI.

For mod_fcgid see:

http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidaccesschecker

For mod_fastcgi see:

http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html#FastCgiAccessChecker